# How to apply a class to a child if all other children are hidden?

Tags: html, css, less, wookmark

I know that this is super simple with jQuery, although I am after a CSS only solution (if possible).

I have a list of divs, with the last item being an error message. I have a simple filtering system, and if none of the divs match the selected filter, I would like to display the error div.

**HTML Structure:**

```
<div id="listHolder">
    <div class="listItem" data-filter-class="["filter1"]"></div>
    <div class="listItem" data-filter-class="["filter2"]"></div>
    <div class="listItem" data-filter-class="["filter1"]"></div>
    <div class="listItem" data-filter-class="["filter4"]"></div>
    <div class="errorItem">Nothing to display here</div>
</div>
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If a div does not match any of the filters, my filter plugin gives them the class of `inactive`. Hence, I need to check if all divs with the class of `listItem` also have the class of `inactive` to give the `errorItem` class the style of `display:block`.

FYI I am using the Wookmark plugin for my list and filtering system. I am also using LESS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is in your requirement:

> I need to check if all divs with the class of listItem also have the class of inactive to give the errorItem class the style of `display:block`

While we can set a style for the final `<div>` element based on its preceding siblings, we can't (without knowing how many there might be) 'check if *all* divs' have the `inactive` class. We can, however, use the sibling combinator (`+`) and a cumbersome selector:

```
.errorItem {
    display: none;
}
.listItem.inactive + .listItem.inactive + .listItem.inactive + .listItem.inactive + errorItem {
    display: block;
}
```

This is, however, ridiculous (especially if there's a dynamic number of elements preceding the `.errorItem` element.

If there's a class-name applied for an element which *does* match the supplied filters, `active` for example, this is much simpler, and achieved by:

```
.errorItem {
    display: block;
}

.listItem.active ~ .errorItem {
    display: none;
}
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, the negation operator is also available (though, obviously, it depends on implementation by the browser in use), which would lend itself to the selector:

```
.errorItem {
    display: block;
}

.listItem:not(.inactive) ~ .errorItem {
    display: none;
}
```

On the whole, I'd strongly suggest using JavaScript to support this functionality, especially since the use of Wookmark implies JavaScript (if not necessarily jQuery) use in the same site already.

Native JavaScript:

```
function hasPrecedingSibling (elem, state) {
    if (!state) {
        return false;
    }
    var found = false,
        cur = elem;
    while (cur.previousElementSibling && found === false) {
        if (cur.classList.contains(state)) {
            found = true;
        }
        else {
            cur = cur.previousElementSibling;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.errorItem'), function (err) {
    err.style.display = hasPrecedingSibling (err, 'active') ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

Comment: If you can do it with `.active`, you can do it with `:not(.inactive)`, right? http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7b1kyfz3/2/

Comment: Actually, that's very true; thanks! (I'll be editing that in, momentarily) :) Ah. I'm sorry, I hadn't seen that you'd added your own answer (I tend not to refresh the page while I'm updating my own answers); if you'd prefer I can excise the `:not(.inactive)` part, if you'd prefer I not duplicate your own approach?

Comment: No worries. You did half the work, I did half the work.

Comment: @Rudie: I appreciate the generosity :)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Used the `:not(.inactive)` method, works very well since the elements are not given an `active` class unfortunately. Thanks for your answer, and your explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's possible: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7b1kyfz3/3/

You want to hide the last item if a previous item is not hidden:

```
.listItem:not(.inactive) ~ .errorItem {
    display: none;
}
```

The demo uses JS just to toggle the `inactive` class, not for display logic of the `errorItem`.

I still agree with all the smart people here though: JS can probably do this better. You're using it already anyway.